# How to express tree using CL?

Tags: common-lisp

I want to convert the following OCaml type (an unbalanced binary tree) to Common Lisp, but as a CL newbie, i donot know how to do it using a dynamic language.

```
type 'a tree =
    Leaf
  | Node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree
```

Any suggestion is appreciated !

Answer (score 9):

A standard cons is your tree node, car being the left subtree, and cdr the right.

See [http://nostoc.stanford.edu/jeff/llisp/13.html (at archive.org now)](https://web.archive.org/web/20120413174515/http://nostoc.stanford.edu/jeff/llisp/13.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Base Common Lisp does not have the discriminated union type definition.

I have found reasonable success using CLOS:

```
(defclass tree () (data left right))
```

See http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-classes.html for more information on using DEFCLASS.

A more memory-efficient approach would be to use DEFSTRUCT instead of DEFCLASS.